# Automate the process of creating variables and assigning them to the dimension of a list

Tags: python, list

If I define a function dependent of the elements of a list, for example a two dimensional function.

```
def func(individual):
    x1 = individual[0]
    x2 = individual[1]
    return x1**2 + x2**3,
```

individual is two dimensional then, how can I parametrize this? so next time if I want to define a 16 variable function for example I don't have to write

```
x1 = individual[0]

x16 = individual[15]


dimensions=5
def func(individual):
    for x in dimensions:
        x = individual[dimensions-1]
    return x1**2 + x2**3, ..., x5
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, depending on your end goal, would be to create a new array to hold the values you want and return the array instead. It might look something like this:

```
def func(individuals):
   resultsArray = [] #Create an empty array
   for i in range(individuals.len()-1): #Iterate through each element of Individuals
      resultsArray[i] = individuals[i]**(i+1) #Set each element of our new array equal to the corresponding element of individuals raised to the power of that item's index + 1
   return resultsArray
```